# Function sameChars doesn't work properly

Tags: python, string, list

> Takes two strings and returns `True` if the strings contain the same characters regardless of the number of occurrences or the order in which they occur. Must consider all characters and is case-sensitive (e.g., `sameChars("AA","a")` returns `False`, while `sameChars("FgFFF","ggFF")` returns `True`.

My code is:

```
def sameChars(s1, s2):
    if s1 <= s1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The function returns `true` if I put:

```
print sameChars('AA', 'a')
```

But it's supposed to return `false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are checking - `s1 <= s1`. This will always be true, since you are checking `s1` with `s1`.

Even if you checked `s1` with `s2`, I do not think this would satisfy your requirement, because `s1 <= s2` is checking whether `s1` is lexicographically lower than `s2`.

The best way for you to go would be to put the characters of s1 and s2 into a set and then check that for equality.

Example -

```
def sameChars(s1, s2):
    if set(s1) == set(s2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Or just return the result of `set(s1) == set(s2)`

```
def sameChars(s1, s2):
    return set(s1) == set(s2)
```

> [**set**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#module-sets) - Unordered collections of unique elements

In Sets the elements would be unique, as they do not allow duplication, and they are unordered so the two sets would be equal, if they have equal elements, irrespective of the order in which the elements appeared.

Comment: Do you think if I use two "for" loops i can make it work?

Comment: why are you using for loops? Why cannot you use `set()` ?

Comment: You can do it with two for loops, but that would just make it complicated. If you cannot use `set` , you can just create lists for both the strings, then sort them, and then check if each element in the list is equal.

Comment: Why not just make it `return set(s1) == set(s2)`?

Comment: Because I don't really now how to use sets.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yea that would also work, thanks, I added the code with least amount of differences from OP's code at first.

Comment: Can you guys give me example with sets?

Comment: a set is a data type in python , that does not allow duplicates and has no order, searching in set data type takes constant time. Good examples and more infromation is present in this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: also can you show me example of my problem using sets?

Comment: The code is there in the answer, are you using that?

Comment: Use the `sameChars` function I gave in the answer.

Comment: ok, when I type:
print sameChars('AA', 'a') it returns true.
I don't know how to make uppercase letters don't equal to lowercase letters

Answer (score 0):

At first:

```
s1 <= s1
```

is always going to be true. You made a typo.

And in general you function is less useful. Everywhere you are using it like `sameChars(s1, s2)` would could simply do a `s1 <= s2` with excatly the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You said in your OP that you want to check *if the strings contain the same characters*. This is one way to do that:

```
>>> s1 = 'Hello'
>>> s2 = 'lo'
>>> s2 in s1
True
>>> s2 = 'LO'
>>> s2 in s1
False
>>>
```

Comment: This will fail if `S2 = 'Helo`, which should match according to OP requirements...